# output template string in a new line

Tags: javascript

When I try to append `\n` to my template `string`, it does not create a new line. I'm not sure where the `code` is behaving in-correctly.

Below is my `template String`:

```
var template = 
'My skills: \n' + 
'<%if(this.showSkills) {%>' +
    '<%for(var index in this.skills) {%>' + 
    '<a href="#"><%this.skills[index]%></a> \n' +
    '<%}%>' +
'<%} else {%>' +
    '<p>none</p> \n' +
'<%}%> \n';
console.log(TemplateEngine(template, {
    skills: ["js", "html", "css"],
    showSkills: true
}));
```

`Template` Engine function

```
var TemplateEngine = function(html, options) {
    var re = /<%([^%>]+)?%>/g, reExp = /(^( )?(if|for|else|switch|case|break|{|}))(.*)?/g, code = 'var r=[];\n', cursor = 0, match;
    var add = function(line, js) {
        js? (code += line.match(reExp) ? line + '\n' : 'r.push(' + line + ');\n') :
            (code += line != '' ? 'r.push("' + line.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '");\n' : '');
        return add;
    }
    while(match = re.exec(html)) {
        add(html.slice(cursor, match.index))(match[1], true);
        cursor = match.index + match[0].length;
    }
    add(html.substr(cursor, html.length - cursor));
    code += 'return r.join("");';
    return new Function(code.replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, '')).apply(options);
}
```

Below is the output:

```
My skills:   <a href="#">js</a>  <a href="#">html</a>  <a href="#">css</a>
```

Here is a working `fiddle`:

http://jsfiddle.net/nrd2ktxn/

I want each of `output` string in a new line like this:

```
My skills:   
<a href="#">js</a>  
<a href="#">html</a>  
<a href="#">css</a>
```

Comment: You wrote your own template engine? That's a bad idea.  What's wrong with using an existing one?

Comment: @Tomalak, if you were right, there should be a single template engine at most...

Comment: Are you writing a template engine or are you actually doing something else? Because if you write your own template engine just to do something else (and that's what it looks ljke to me), then you are making a mistake. Client side templating is a solved problem. Don't reinvent the wheel when there are so many superb and completey free wheels are available.

Comment: And your attempt is a big wide security hole, it's completely, entirely inadequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you just add quotes around the input text and escape inner quotes:

```
'r.push("' + line.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '")'
```

But if `line` contains [line terminators](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.3), it will produce invalid JS which will throw when you eval it.

Effectively, removing all line breaks in the code solves it:

```
code.replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, '')
```

However, it gets rid of the line breaks in the input text.

Instead, you should handle line terminators. Something like

```js
'r.push("' + line
  .replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')        // Escape the escaping character
  .replace(/"/g, '\\"')          // Escape double quotes
  .replace(/\n/g, '\\n')         // Escape <LF>
  .replace(/\r/g, '\\r')         // Escape <CR>
  .replace(/\u2028/g, '\\u2028') // Escape <LS>
  .replace(/\u2029/g, '\\u2029') // Escape <PS>
+ '");'
```

```js
var TemplateEngine = function(html, options) {
  var re = /<%([^%>]+)?%>/g, reExp = /(^( )?(if|for|else|switch|case|break|{|}))(.*)?/g, code = 'var r=[];\n', cursor = 0, match;
  function escapeText(s) {
    return '"' + s
    .replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
    .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
    .replace(/\n/g, '\\n')
    .replace(/\r/g, '\\r')
    .replace(/\u2028/g, '\\u2028')
    .replace(/\u2029/g, '\\u2029')
    + '"';
  }
  var add = function(line, js) {
    js? (code += line.match(reExp) ? line + '\n' : 'r.push(' + line + ');\n') :
    (code += line != '' ? 'r.push(' + escapeText(line) + ');\n' : '');
    return add;
  }
  while(match = re.exec(html)) {
    add(html.slice(cursor, match.index))(match[1], true);
    cursor = match.index + match[0].length;
  }
  add(html.substr(cursor, html.length - cursor));
  code += 'return r.join("");';
  return new Function(code).apply(options);
}    

var template = 
    'My skills: \n' + 
    '<%if(this.showSkills) {%> \n' +
    '<%for(var index in this.skills) {%> \n' + 
    '<a href="#"><%this.skills[index]%></a> \n' +
    '<%}%> \n' +
    '<%} else {%> \n' +
    '<p>none</p> \n' +
    '<%}%> \n';
console.log(TemplateEngine(template, {
  skills: ["js", "html", "css"],
  showSkills: true
}));
```